# Alamofire4 throwing "extra argument method" when using method: .post

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I've been transitioning from Swift2/AF3 to Swift3/AF4 and its been an absolute nightmare. Xcode is throwing "extra argument method" errors, but this is false, which makes it near impossible for me to find what the actual error is. In multiple places around my code I have

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: parameters,
 encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON() { response in ... }
```

where `url` is `string`, `method` is one of the enums available, and `parameters` and `headers` are `[String: Any]`. But when I change method to .post I get the "extra argument" error. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this. I tried both with a `.validate()` and without.

```
let url = "myStringHere"
let params = ["myString": myString] as [String: Any]
let headers = ["Authorization": myString, "AnotherString": stringValue] as [String: Any]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, 
  encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in ... }
```

I added a line break for readability. The `validate()` would go between `request()` and `responseJSON` like I do for `.put` methods, which I've updated to the new syntax without having this issue. I'm at a total loss here.

**edit**: just wanted to say that I have ensured the types by going into the .post request() and option+clicking the variables to double check their types. The only one that doesn't work with option+click is `method: .post`. I've checked other answers but none of them work, most are just issues from `encoding: .json` -> `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` but you can clearly see that's what I have.

**edit2**: Tried switching `encoding` to `URLEncoding.httpBody` but that also hasn't worked. I'm getting a million errors off Alamofire that my Xcode can't even process them all at once. Does this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "headers" argument type is [String : String], not [String : Any]. You got caught by misleading error description.

Comment: oh my god I think this fixed it. My code uses AF everywhere so I have literally hundreds of errors to fix by myself. Been banging my head against the wall for so long. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I would recommend on making a so-called adapter like RequestHandler. The only object that uses Alamofire API. This way the migration to the new version of Alamofire is gonna be in one place since other parts of your project would use API of adapter.

Comment: So something like making my own MyRequest.request() that takes in the arguments needed for the AF.request(), and then when AF code changes I only need to change that one function in the MyRequest class?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Not a lot of fun to update every occurrence of some Alamofire API if they change argument name or something. It's a common practice to create your own adapter to work with some framework.